# query timeout error in “Data Flow Task”- Source part of SSIS

Tags: ssis, teradata

I am getting query timeout error in “Data Flow Task”- Source part of SSIS, whenever the teradata source connectivity is slow. The query is “select * from ” and the table contains only 100-200 rows. I tried to set the Commandtimout to “0”,but even then the query times out after 30 seconds.

Can anyone please help with either to increase the timeout value in SSIS or to decrease the query run time in teradata ?

Comment: If the source table in Teradata contains only 200 rows are you experiencing a blocked session or delayed session based on workload management rules? What are the Teradata DBAs telling you? A simple SELECT of 200 rows from a Teradata base table should come back well under 30 seconds even on a busy system. Are you sure you are querying a table and not a view?

Comment: thanks for your reply..solved the issue by changing the ssis properties..

Comment: @PawanKumarJha, please post an answer (not comment) with exact steps needed to solve the problem. Community may benefit from your solution.

Comment: The “Command Timeout” property doesn’t solve the purpose. For this property to be set, we have to override the default timeout properties in the SSIS(SQL Server Management Studio) level.
Tools-Options-Database Tools-Query and View Designers            (-Cancel long running query after n seconds)   
                                                              Table and Database Designers->Table and Diagram Options        (-Transaction time out after n seconds)

Set this “n” to more to override the default timeout value.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the query time-out of a particular Data Flow Task like this:

1. In the Control Flow view, select the Data Flow Task
2. Switch to the Data Flow view
3. Select the data source or target you want to change the time-out for
4. Get the properties (hit F4)

You can set the CommandTimeout from the Properties page.

See https://forums.teradata.com/forum/connectivity/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-and-timeout-errors

Given your particular circumstances, changing the time-out might not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It could be how the query is being interpreted by the query engine itself. Instead of using a "SELECT *", specify the columns that you are going to be using; i.e. "SELECT first_name, last_name ...".

1. Open the Data Flow, and double-click your source.
2. Under Data access mode, select SQL Command.
3. Write out your query with all the columns you need.
4. Save.

You may have to correct your column definitions in the flow, but if the metadata matches, you should be able to just review and save.

I have had to do this to work around timeouts even when using a view where I wanted all the columns back.

Comment: I just realized that the original question is 4 years old. I will leave the answer here, in case it helps someone else that comes along.